# Do damage conveyance socketables stack?

Tags: torchlight-2

Let's say I have two socketables, each with this effect:

`Conveys 1000 physical damage over 5 seconds`

If I put both of these on one weapon, do I get 2000 physical damage over 5 seconds (stacked) or are all other damage conveyance effects ignored in excess of one?

I know that the effect icon appears by the enemy's health bar so you know the effect is in effect, but that only shows when you hover over the enemy and the icon is located up at the top of the screen.  To get to it, you have to move your mouse off the enemy, so it ends up disappearing before you get mouse over it.

Comment: You can actually hover over an enemy's effect icons by: (a) clicking the enemy and then (b) dragging the mouse cursor up to the desired icon **while keeping the left mouse button down held down**. This took me forever to figure out, but it is doable.

Comment: @JonahBishop Awesome, it worked.  However, while holding down the button, my character continues to attack, causing the effect to accumulate (which is not the same as stacking).  I'd like to just attack once and then look at the effect icon to see what effect a single blow has on the target.  Any idea how to do this?

Comment: Also, I tested this by attacking a town dummy.

Comment: I think your best bet might be to hit the enemy, run out of range, then **shift+click** them to prevent your character from running towards them.

Answer (score 1):

All damage over time gems work independently without interacting with each other.  In other words, by adding gems you add their effects.

Comment: This is not always true for skills. For example, if you execute it will use both weapon's gems, however if you are using a skill like Ravage, the off-hand "coveys x dmg over x seconds" won't be applied.

Comment: This question is talking about 2 gems on *one* weapon.  Dual-wield and execute are irrelevant here - that's a different mechanic.  Gems only apply to the thing they are in.